# Register different objects corresponding to an interface in Asp.Net DependencyInjection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have a use case where I want to register a service multiple times with different configs. The registration of this service is done in a builder extension method. Please check the below code for context.

1. If I add `SomeService` as a Singleton then it's not working because the ServiceCollection is not resolving the correct instance for me.
2. In Autofac, I can use `NamedService` or `KeyedService` but that option is not available here. Is there a way to effectively solve this problem?

```cs
// a builder extension method
public static IServiceCollection AddSomeService(
    this IServiceCollection services, string myConfig)
{
    services.AddSingleton<TokenCredential>(fa =>
    {
        // a complex logic to register some singleton services which would be
        // useful in below service registration
    });
    services.AddSingleton(fac => // Here I think, AddSingleton is not correct
    {
        ServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

        // some complex logic using serviceCollection and myConfig goes here
        ISomeService someService =
            serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider().GetSomeService();
        return someService;
    });

    return services;
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSomeService("dbConfig");
    services.AddSingleton<DbRepo, IDbRepo>();

    // I want to register SomeService again with different config and pass it
    // to register CacheRepo
    services.AddSomeService("cacheConfig"); 
    services.AddSingleton<CacheRepo, ICacheRepo>();
}

public class DbRepo : IDbRepo
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;
    public DbRepo (ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService = someService;
    }
}

public class CacheRepo : ICacheRepo
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;
    public CacheRepo (ISomeService someService)
    {
        this.someService = someService;
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK this is not possible because how would the DI container know which config to use when trying to inject a `ISomeService`?  I would suggest either writing a factory class and injecting that (and then using the factory to get the specific implementation you need), or using specific interfaces (even if they don't have any additional functionality) and binding those to the different configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a factory class, e.g.:

```cs
public interface ISomeServiceFactory
{
    ISomeService Create(string config);
}

public sealed class SomeServiceFactory : ISomeServiceFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider provider;

    public SomeServiceFactory(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    public ISomeService Create(string config)
    {
        // do your processing here instead - you have access to the service provider
    }
}
```

Then you can add that to the `IServiceCollection`:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeServiceFactory>(provider => new SomeServiceFactory(provider));
}
```

And inject that into your repos instead:

```cs
public class DbRepo : IDbRepo
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;
    public DbRepo(ISomeServiceFactory factory)
    {
        this.someService = factory.Create("dbConfig");
    }
}

public class CacheRepo : ICacheRepo
{
    private readonly ISomeService someService;
    public CacheRepo(ISomeServiceFactory factory)
    {
        this.someService = factory.Create("cacheConfig");
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a nice and clean solution. The only problem in my case would be that it would need a lot of file changes. Otherwise this is a good approach.